# Experimenting with creating OCR in tensorflow, what to do after training on letters?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tensorflow, ocr

Honestly, i'm just stuck and can't think. I have worked hard to create an amazing model that can read letters, but how do I move on to words, sentences, paragraphs and full papers?

This is a general question so forgive me for not providing code, but assume I have successfully trained a network at recognizing letters of many kinds and many fonts, with all sorts of different noise and distortions in the image.

(just to be technical, the images the model is trained on are 36*36 grayscale images only, and the model is a simple classifier with some `conv2d` layers)

Now I want to use this well-trained model with all it's parameters and give it something to read, to turn in into a full OCR program. This is where i'm stuck. I want to give the program a photo/scan of a paper, and have it recognize all the letters. But how do I "predict" using my model, when the image is obviously larger than the images it was trained on of single letter?

I have tried adding an additional layer of `conv2d` that would try to read features of parts of the image, but that was too complicated and I couldn't figure it out.

I have also looked at `opencv` programs that recognize where there is text in the image and crop that out, but none that I could find separate out single letters that could now be fed to the trained model to try and read.

What is my next step from here?

Answer (score 1):

If the fonts of the letters will be the same throughout the whole image you could use the so called: "**sliding window technique**"

You start from the upper left corner and slide your scan window to the right for the size of the letter until you reach the end of the paper.

The sliding window will be the size of the scanned letter and when inputted to your neural network it will output the letter. Save those letters somewhere.

Other methods would include changing your neural network and being smarter about detecting blobs of text on the scanned paper

If you are looking for an off-the-shelf solution take a look at [Tessaract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/).

Comment: Could you expand on "sliding window" a bit? I thought about implementing something like that but I'm assuming that by "sliding" a few pixels each time, I might miss out on letters if the "slide" is too big, or read the same letter multiple times if the slide is too small. The size of the slide needed is unknown and different for each paper. Are there any models that deal with that?

Comment: You could try with different window sizes and see which one gives you the best accuracy for different parts of the image and choose the best size of the sliding window.

Comment: use the same window size and slide-length on the whole image, then downscale the image a bit and slide again, then downscale image and slide, and so on. That's a multiscale approach. But depending on your clasifier there might be another problem: Is it invariant to rotation and perspective distortions, or do you assume upright rectilinear papers as input?

Comment: or maybe use a stroke width transform to guess font sizes or sth ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following links for ideas:

- [STN-OCR: A single Neural Network for Text Detection and Text Recognition](https://github.com/Bartzi/stn-ocr)
- [STN-OCR on Medium](https://medium.com/syncedreview/stn-ocr-a-single-neural-network-for-text-detection-and-text-recognition-220debe6ded4)
- [Attention-based Extraction of Structured Information from Street View Imagery](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/attention_ocr)
- [Another Attention-based OCR Repo](https://github.com/emedvedev/attention-ocr)
- [A model using both CNN and LSTM](https://github.com/weinman/cnn_lstm_ctc_ocr)